# where to download @font-face files and how to reference

Tags: javascript, html, css, font-face

I'm fairly new to programming in general and only completely getting started with some basic web-design stuff.  I'm trying to make use of @font-face for my web app, issue is its not a registered webpage yet, and not sure if it will be. Most of the tutorials and forum stuff I've found are way over my head, and I'm just trying to come up to speed and haven't had much luck.  Any explanations on how to use it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!
Here's one of the multiply things I've tried, sorry there's really not much to go off of.  I'm trying to use this font from font squirrel.  I'm trying to use it when the webpage isnt actually hosted on a server and am not quite sure how to do that.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Titillium-Thin;
    src: local('C:\Font');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the font file in your src

```
@font-face {
    font-family: myFirstFont;
    src: url('font\roboto.woff');
}
```

And then you use it like this

```
html, body {
    font-family: myFirstFont;
}
```